# How to import a specific variable or all my variables as a character in R

Tags: r, import

```
fs::dir_ls(

  path = paste("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["user"],
               "/Dropbox/66_COHORTE_obe/00_RAW_DATA/1_GROUPE BARIA/SEJOURS/",
               sep = ""),
  glob="*SEJOUR*.csv",
  type="file"
)%>%{
  tibble(path=.,
         data=map(., .%>%
                    read_csv2(show_col_types=FALSE)))
}->all_files_SEJ
```

I've used this code to import a large number of data sets together. But some variables are imported incorrectly. Either they're transformed into a date, or they're transformed into a number (for example a number folowed by `e` and then by another number become a number. I think it's considering `e` as exponentiate or something like that) What I'd like is to import the variable in character so that it's not denatured. What modification could I make to my code so that certain variables of interest are imported as characters or even so that all variables are imported as characters?

Comment: If you look at the `?read_csv2` help page you can use the `colClasses` argument, e.g., `colClasses = c(col1 = "character", col5 = "character", col7 = "numeric")`. But also sometimes R prints large numbers in scientific notation - what you're seeing may be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read this. Can't I name the variables explicitly, since all datasets have globally the same variable but not always at the same position. Otherwise it would solve the problem, if I could import all the variables in each dataset as a character.

Comment: It's not about position, it's column names. But if you want **everything** as character you can just say `colClasses = "character"`.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. Actually it is ```col_types="c"``` instead of colClasses with read_csv2. I Think you considered it as read.csv2 of R base